# large gaps between text

Tags: formatting

i get big white gaps between text, sometimes between text and figures. i have the float package for figure placement using [H].
I cant seem to find what is causing the issue. i attached a link to my packages and
a screenshot of the issue.

https://pastebin.com/bDVPai8C

[image: gaps]

Comment: You answered your own question: the `[H]` specifier is the culprit. Use `[htp]` and let figures float.

Comment: whats sorcery is this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @pit No sorcery: the `[H]` option defined by the `float` package *can* be used, but it requires extensive editorial work. It's much simpler and also typographically sound to let figures find their place as LaTeX seems fit; when the document is finished as far as the text is concerned, you can try and improve the figure placement.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat

Comment: `[H]` means "the figure must go here, and I don't care about the consequences".  TeX doesn't like lots of blank space, so it spreads your paragraphs out so that the blank space is between the paragraphs instead of at the bottom of your page.  Since you apparently care about those consequences, don't use `[H]`.

Comment: the whole point of `[H]` is to _choose_ ugly white space rather than let LaTeX move the floats to avoid bad space at page breaks. The intention is that the author then takes manual control and moves the figure by hand, or writes extra words to fille the gaps or whatever. It is a tool of last resort to take over final copy editing control.